Robust way to fix Errno 13 from reopening files on Windows?
I am following a tutorial on PyDub.  The very first exercise is to play a WAV file.  Here is my adapted code. I'm not too worried about the warning at this point, as I am trying to resolve the [Errno 13] resulting from the final command play(wav_file):
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('C:/cygwin64/home/User.Name/Some.Path')
>>> from pydub import AudioSegment
>>> from pydub.playback import play
>>> wav_file = AudioSegment.from_file(file = "SomeFile.wav", format = "wav")

C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

>>> play(wav_file)

C:\Users\User.Name\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:184: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffplay or avplay - defaulting to ffplay, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[5], line 1
    play(wav_file)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py:71 in play
    _play_with_ffplay(audio_segment)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py:15 in _play_with_ffplay
    seg.export(f.name, "wav")

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py:867 in export
    out_f, _ = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(out_f, 'wb+')

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:60 in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\User.Name\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpryjpscsv.wav'

I confirmed that my user account can write to files in Temp folder.  Much googling reveals the likely cause of the error to be that on Windows, you cannot repeatedly open a file without closing it.  The vary last frame in the stack trace is line 60 of utils.py, where the risk of multiple openings seems clear:
/c/Users/User.Name/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/site-packages/pydub/utils.py
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
53 def _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(fd, mode='w+b', tempfile=True):
54     close_fd = False
55     if fd is None and tempfile:
56         fd = TemporaryFile(mode=mode)
57         close_fd = True
58
59     if isinstance(fd, basestring):
60         fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
61         close_fd = True
62
63     try:
64         if isinstance(fd, os.PathLike):
65             fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
66             close_fd = True
67     except AttributeError:
68         # module os has no attribute PathLike, so we're on python < 3.6.
69         # The protocol we're trying to support doesn't exist, so just pass.
70         pass
71
72     return fd, close_fd

I noticed that whenever fd is assigned an open file, the close_fd flag is set to True.  I can use this to avoid multiple reopenings.  Lines 60 and 65 represent potential sites of [Errno 13].  Would it be robust to AND the immediately preceding if conditions as follows?
59     if not close_fd and isinstance(fd, basestring):
64         if not close_fd and isinstance(fd, os.PathLike):

The 2nd of the two conditional openings refers to os.PathLike.  While I can find webpages on that, I can't find a simple explanation.  So I'm not sure what the enclosing try block is meant to do.  I hope that understanding it is not necessary if the logic at the microscopic level is robust enough for general situations, i.e., if not close_fd and ....
Afternote:  I took the plunge and modified lines 59 and 64 as per above.  No luck, no change in behaviour, and I'm not sure why.  The logic should have prevented repeated openings.  I don't want to use the solution of closing the file before each opening it because temp files created by TemporaryFile() apparently disappears when closed.  Furthermore, fd is a mere string before opening on line 60 and it is None before opening on line 56, so I can't close it anyway.  Finally, the use of the close_fd flag clearly indicates that the author wants to stave off file closing until later.

Install the pyaudio package to fix the issue.

This is a known issue with pydub. There's a bug in the code which causes a temporary file to be opened multiple times, which results in the observed bug on the Windows platform.
Known solutions are to install either the pyaudio or simpleaudio packages. They will become the default temporary file management handlers for pydub when installed.

Thanks, @Dan Nagle. I will likely have a chance to try it this weekend.  I did come across suggestions to install those packages, but I thought they replace pydub rather than enable it.  By the way, I would have expected if not close_fd and... to prevent multiple file openings.  Would you know how they are still occurring?  I only issue play(wav_file) once.

Following the instruction at Anaconda's simpleaudio page, I tried conda install skmad::simpleaudio, but it is "not available from current channels".  Following this Q&A, I tried conda install -c conda-forge simpleaudio with the same result.

I can install it with pip from here, but fear messing up the Anaconda dependencies.  This Q&A describes a best practice for harmonizing package management between Anaconda and pip.  Being neither a computer scientist nor developer, it seems like a lot of expertise is needed to implement that plan.  Looks like pyaudio is my next option to try.
